# Ruby stop iterate in case block if return true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below if block:

```
  scoring = if match_invoice_number(resource)
              3
            elsif match_amount(resource) && match_vendor(resource)
              2
            elsif match_vendor(resource)
              1
            else
              0
            end
```

which I replace by below case:

```
  def score(resource)
    case resource
    when match_invoice_number(resource) then 0
    when match_amount(resource) && match_vendor(resource) then 1
    when match_vendor(resource) then 3
    else -1
    end
  end
```

I thought it would break this loop when some `when` element returned true. E.g. `match_amount(resource) && match_vendor(resource)` will return true - it `case` break and return 1. How to achieve that?

Comment: Firstly, there is no loop to break here. Secondly, you are correct - case will stop evaluating further when clauses once it finds the matching one. If this is not a case for your code that it means that problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You write "Ruby stop iterate in case block if return true", but there is no iteration in your code. Also, you write "I thought it would break this loop", but there is no loop in the code you showed, so what is "this loop" you are referring to? It's also hard to tell what is going on without knowing the definitions of `resource`, `match_amount`, `match_vendor`, and `match_invoice_number`. As long their return values properly respond to the `===` message, the code should work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `case resource` ruby compares your resource with every expression using `===`. It seems, that `match...` methods returns booleans, so that you will always get a default value.

To make this work you could get rid of resource. With empty case you will get an expected behaviour.

```
def score(resource)
  case
  when match_invoice_number(resource) then 0
  when match_amount(resource) && match_vendor(resource) then 1
  when match_vendor(resource) then 3
  else -1
  end
end
```

However, it is not a [good practice](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/EmptyCaseCondition) to use empty cases. If-else is the tool that solves this task better.

```
def score(resource)
  if match_invoice_number(resource)
    3
  elsif match_amount(resource) && match_vendor(resource)
    2
  elsif match_vendor(resource)
    1
  else
    0
  end
end
```